# Execute SSIS Package when SQL and Visual studio is not installed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Is it possible to execute the SSIS package(.dtsx file) into the System when SQL and Visual Studio is not installed into the system.

Minimum Requirement to execute the SSIS Package ?
Kindly Suggest how to proceed in this scenario ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You must have either Integration Services installed or BIDS (2005 - 2008R2) / SSDT (2012).

Comment: And that installation will need a license lest you run afoul of the MS licensing arm...

Comment: Thanks Brian and Billinkc for the reply..!!
Can we install Integration services runtime engine without installing sql server..?? Is that also needs license..!!

One more query :-
Can we make a Cab/installer or exe of the SSIS Package that hold all the dlls and then try to execute in the system ..?? Is this possible ?
Thanks

Comment: You can install BIDS with just the SQL client tools, but not the DB engine itself.  However, my understanding is that you still need a license to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  article. There are other methods you can try, like you can run as a job in SQL Server or  you can use the DTEXEC.EXE Command Line Utility  to execute SSIS packages.
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1775/different-ways-to-execute-a-sql-server-ssis-package/

Comment: This still requires that the Integration Services runtimes be installed.

Comment: Thanks Kumar..!!
I have just followed the same procedure, but that doesn't work. The reason SSIS services are not installed...!!